# How do I mount Shares from an iomega ix4-200d?

Tags: networking, hard-drive

How do I mount Shares from an Iomega ix4-200d?

Plug-and-play from Windows with the included installation CD, but not a word about Linux.

It looks like there are several ways to do it; I have put my current solution below.

Comment: Can any of you guys give me a hand please? [My similar thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1391780/looks-an-easy-mistake-cifs-mount-failed-w-return-code-2-etc-fstab)

Answer (score 2):

Not knowing anything about such endeavors, this took me about 4 hours to figure out.  It turns out the procedure is very simple.

1. Log into your ix4 from the web
   browser (you should see the IP
   address on the drive screen).
2. Click the "Network" icon then the
   "Protocol" icon.
3. See the little penguin next to "NFS"?  That's your
   Linux documentation (nice of them).
4. Turn NFS on.  Yes, it was off by
   default.  Again, that was nice of
   them.
5. `sudo mount -t nfs
   192.168.1.113:/nfs/SHARENAME /mnt/yourdir`
6. `SHARENAME` above is just the name of your Share on the ix4 without embellishment.  Keep the /nfs.  Obviously, change the IP address to whatever your's is.
7. `/mnt/yourdir` is a directory you've created with mkdir.  Actually, it can be anywhere.  /mnt is the canonical place.
8. If your Ubuntu installation was like mine, the above command will fail because you do not have a file called `mount.nfs` in your `/sbin` directory.  Quite an oversight on your part.  Install it with `apt-get install nfs-common`.

Once you get it working you can put a similar line in `/etc/fstab`, so your Shares are automatically mounted.  [Section 4.2 and 4.3 of the Sourceforge nfs resource](http://nfs.sourceforge.net/nfs-howto/ar01s04.html) explain how to do it.

Kudos to [Eric Crossley's Blog](http://communities.vmware.com/people/ecrossley/blog/2010/01/13/ix4200d-iomega-4tb-nas-and-ubuntu-9x#comments) which has the idea of mounting as NFS and the basic mount command.  He has a few more useful ix4 setups there as well.

Comment: I have had an ix2 200 for two years and that's the way I use to connect to it. You could also connect using samba or ftp, but I think nfs is the better.

Answer (score 1):

I just installed it, thanks for your help but I needed a few different settings.

```
sudo mount //192.168.1.89/public ~/Iomega -o uid=1000, gid=1000,rw,username='admin',password=#########
```

I just want to point out the differences (and might be stating the obvious? but I am new to Linux):

- addressing the network works only with `//a.b.c.d.` and very mean,
- the (German) settings on the `ix2` tells you to mount to `//a.b.c.d/nfs/....` and this should be `/public`.

Answer (score 1):

I've got access with a little distinct syntax:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=administrador,password=XXXXXX //10.20.12.21/NASIII /home/rsouza/NAS
```

Don't forget to enable NFS on the NAS (Network-Protocols)

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't abide the fact that on Windows I could access the shares with out  credentials but on my Linuxes it kept asking for password and/or giving 'Access denied'.

This finally worked for me.

In the Iomega Control Panel (web GUI), go to `Network>Protocols`.

Enable `NFS`.

Then go to `Storage>Shares`.

You should see the share folders all listed (Documents, Pictures, etc).

Expand each one and you should see options like 'Information', 'NFS', etc.

Expand 'NFS' and it will `reveal the NFS share name.`

In my case the shares had these names:

Documents = `/nfs/Documents`
Movies = `/nfs/Movies`
i.e.

```
{ShareName} = /nfs/{ShareName}
```

etc

So, on my Ununtu server i first installed the NFS (and CIFS for good measure):

```
apt install nfs-utils
apt install cifs-utils
```

Then I wrote this script to handle the mounting:

```
for D in Documents Pictures Backups Music Movies
do
   banner $D
   umount /mnt/ts1/$D
   mkdir /mnt/ts1/$D
   mount.nfs 10.0.0.101:/nfs/$D /mnt/ts1/$D
done
```

No need to provide username and password - access just as you would via Windows Explorer.